# What's the difference between ResponseEntity<MyClass> and ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Basically I have two methods in controller that have these return types: ResponseEntity and ResponseEntity. I can't see any difference between their responses.

```
@GetMapping("/example/json")
public ResponseEntity<Student> exampleJson() {
  Student student = Student.builder().rollNo(10).name("Student1").className("first").build();
  return ResponseEntity.ok(student);
}
```

What will change if instead of public `ResponseEntity<Student> exampleJson()` I will have `ResponseEntity exampleJson()`?

**EDIT**

In my example, I have this method

```
  @GetMapping("/departments/{departmentId}")
    public ResponseEntity  getDepartmentById(@PathVariable("departmentId") Long departmentId) {
        Optional<Department> department = null;
        try {
            department = departmentService.getDepartmentById(departmentId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Can't get department because there is no department with that id");

        }
        DepartmentDTO departmentDTO = (DepartmentDTO) modelMapper.convertToType(department.get(), DepartmentDTO.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(departmentDTO);

    }
```

Let's say that I want to have a type for my ResponseEntity, something like
`public ResponseEntity<DepartmentDTO> getDepartmentById(...)`

this `return ResponseEntity.ok().body(departmentDTO);` will work fine but this: `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Can't get department because there is no department with that id");` will give an error as it says that

```
Required type: ResponseEntity<DepartmentDTO>
Provided: ResponseEntity<String>
```

I looked over some articles about this topic but I still don't understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Kind of, now I know how a raw type works and the difference between it and generic type. I will make an edit to explain better my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can define what type of object your API will return.  Basically you're defining a contract for this API.

Answer (score 0):

ResponseEntity alone is same as specifying return type as object ,as Object is default mother of all classes.
ResponseEntity  is being specific.
As to answer ,what happens if you do not mention specifics of return type object , it will show "Raw use of parameterized class" warning.
In addition when some other application is consuming the responce, they would prefer to have the specific details of responce type to consume it.